# Що таке "карта", "нароковац", "дошіковац" з пісні "Кедь ми прийшла карта"?

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів, діалекти

Питання про декілька незрозумілих слів у пісні:

> Кедь ми прийшла **карта нароковац**,
>   став я свого неня **дошіковац**:
>   "Неню ж ти мій неню,
>   вчинь ми таку волю,
>   йди за мене служить
>   на ту войну.

Загальний смисл такий "коли прийшов **(якийсь документ)** **(служити у війську)** став я свого батька **(просити)**".

Чи точний це "переклад", чи є якісь відтінки смислу, які тут зникли?
(Наприклад не "просити" а "вмовляти" і т.і.)

UPD: І ще, було б цікаво дізнатися з якої/яких мов ці слова (чеська?)

Comment: чудова пісня. карта [нароковац](http://webslovnik.zoznam.sk/synonymicky-slovnik/narokovat) - то здається саме виклик на військовий вишкіл перед війною, повістка. [дошіковац](http://bara.ujc.cas.cz/ssjc/search.php?hledej=Hledat&heslo=%C5%A1ik&sti=11900&where=hesla) - то напевно вмовляти, бо наскільки я розумію нень героя пісні загинув на минулій війні, тож то так би мовити, образне, майже іронічне вмовляння

Answer (score 22, accepted):

По-перше, ця вся пісня трохи не українською, а русинською мовою (*кедь, лем*, інфінітиви на *-ц* – це типові русинизми), в якій багато словакізмів.

По-друге, там описано зовсім иншу колізію, ніж те, про що пише @Chizh. Справа в тому, що в Австро-Угорщині рекрутаційна команда приходила до села, маючи певну квоту, скільки людей треба набрати до війська. Селян призивного віку збирали та кидали жереб, кому йти **нароковац**, виконувати свій обов’язок, тобто служити у війську. **Прийшла карта** саме й означає, що хлопцеві випав отой жереб. Та це був ще не кінець життя, **карту** можна було комусь передати, якщо той був згідний, от герой пісні й почав **дошіковац**, просити свого тата перейняти в нього ту карту та піти служити за нього, бо, як співається далі, в героя скоро народиться дитина.

Я вважаю, що різниця тут принципова. Погодьтеся, коли вам приходить повістка на ваше ім’я, як зараз, ви не можете когось иншого попросити піти до війська замість вас.

Comment: @znatno, дякуємо за запропоноване редагування допису. Ваше формулювання значно відрізняється від погляду автора відповіді. Подібні зміни варто обговорювати у коментарях перед тим, як їх пропонувати. Під час обговорення можна також навести посилання на авторитетні джерела, які підкріплюють вашу аргументацію, це збільшить імовірність переконати інших користувачів у правильності вашого погляду на проблему.

Comment: @znatno - Різниця між окремою мовою й діалектом дуже примарна, її  часто обумовлено політикою, а не лінґвістикою. Особисто я вважаю русинську окремою мовою, бо на це є мовознавчі підстави. А от у Сербії в Автономному краї [Воєводина](https://rue.wikipedia.org/wiki/Войводина) (Аутономна покрајина Војводина) русинська – одна з офіційних мов. Чи по-вашому там теж українською говорять? Офіційно назва тієї мови «русински». Ну й [Вікіпедія русинською](https://rue.wikipedia.org/wiki/Головна_сторінка) вам у подарунок.

Answer (score 11):

Увага, деякі висновки зроблені у цій відповіді не дуже коректні. Зверніть увагу на [цю відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/557/92)

маємо два словосполучення з якими мусимо розібратися:

1. карта нароковац
2. дошіковац

в [мові сусіднього народу](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) є схожі за звучанням слова

- [`karta`](http://slovnik.azet.sk/pravopis/?q=karta) зі значеннями

> hovor. korešpondenčný lístok, [pohľadnica](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)
>
> zastar. list papiera;

- [`narokovat' si`](http://slovnik.azet.sk/pravopis/?q=narokovat%27%20si) зі значенням

> nárokovať si, zastar. i nárokovať, -uje, -ujú nedok. (čo) uplatňovať nárok, požadovať

- [`došikovať`](http://slovnik.azet.sk/synonyma/?q=do%C5%A1ikova%C5%A5) зі значенням:

> [spôsobiť](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/induce), že sa [niekto ocitne v istom stave](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empathy), že [niekto niečo urobí](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persuade), že niekto [k niečomu dospeje](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encourage)

Тобто герою пісні <s>прийшов [лист щастя з певного вимогою](http://zbruc.eu/node/25107) (*карта нароковац*)</s><sup>[вірне пояснення звороту](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/557/92)</sup>, і він почав [натякати](http://slovnik.azet.sk/synonyma/?q=do%C5%A1ikova%C5%A5) (*дошиковувати*) свому батьку, що він мовляв [знається на цій справі краще](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_Army) і тому:

> Неню ж ти мій неню,
> вчинь ми таку волю,
> йди за мене служить
> на ту войну

також далі з пісні ми дізнаємося, що:

> Ніхто не заплаче, ні отець, ні матка,
> [Лем](http://sum.in.ua/s/krim) за мном заплачут три дівчатка.
> А єдна заплаче, бо я її брат,
> А друга заплаче, бо я її сват,
> А третя заплаче, бо плакати мусить,
> Бо вона від мене першінь носить.

*таким чином, повторюючи потім перший куплет, герой пісні **дошиковує** слухачеві, що <s>його доля схожа на долю його батька або діда</s><sup>*</sup> йому [в той час було](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kiedy) важко та лячно за своє майбутнє. Але поділитися він таким своїм розумінням ситуації може вже тільки зі слухачем*

<sup>*</sup>
дійсно, якщо герою у 1914 році близько 20-30, то його батько навряд чи бував у такій самій ситуації мобілізації на велику війну як і герой, тільки якщо його батька мобілізували на придушення внутрішнього повстання у 1887 у Відні. А от дід героя теоретично міг брати участь в [Австро-Пруській війні](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) чи навіть у [Другій війні за Шлезвіґ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%A8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B3)