# What is "допавши зміни" in "І так любо, допавши зміни, налітати, мов княжа рать"?

Tags: значення-слів, non-native-speaker

From a poem by [Яр Славутич](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%AF%D1%80):

> Нами снили поліські пущі,
>   Гайдамацькі яри в полях.
>   І прийшли ми до них, живущі,
>   Подолавши пекельний шлях.
>
> Повернулися із Берези,
>   З-за Байкалу, із Соловків,
>   Багатющі, неначе крези,
>   Гнівом часу, жалем віків.
>
> Від Чернігова до Чернівців,
>   З-під Лугані за гордий Львів
>   По залогах стоять упівці,
>   Розбуялий відплати гнів.
>
> І так любо, **допавши зміни**,
>   Налітати, мов княжа рать.
>   Нам – визвольникам України –
>   Не приречено умирать.

What is **допавши зміни**? I looked up **[допадати](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)** - there are three meanings. Does it mean "wishing for a change" here?

Comment: For me it is mostly _to catch_.

Comment: можливо, http://sum.in.ua/s/dopasty значення 1 http://sum.in.ua/s/zmina значення 5, як можемо судити з "мотив глибокого закорінення українських повстанців у національний ґрунт відлунює в поезії
«Нами снили поліські пущі…» (1944), де потверджується спадкоємність визвольних потенцій у народові, що
подивував колись світ Запорозькою Січчю. http://ekhsuir.kspu.edu/bitstream/123456789/2252/1/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%A3%D0%9F%D0%90.pdf

Comment: @chizh як на мене, це вже майже відповідь. Щонайменше, версія.

Comment: @P.Vowk  поки що це не більше ніж спекуляція :) дочекаюся як bounty expires і тоді запошчу

Comment: @chizh - don't you want to get the bounty? ))

Comment: @CopperKettle I want to believe Ukr.SE is not about just points :) If I were sure about my version I'd posted it right away. But this time I'd wait while bounty expires, then I post my wrong answer and after a while YellowSky will come and post a right answer as it already has happend once [in this post](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/469/92)

Comment: @chizh - you can post it as a "community answer" ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Етимологічний словник української мови.  Том 4. 2003.

> Падати - див Пасти.   Пасти. Допасти - добратися, схопити. Допастися -
> з жадністю взяти за щось, накинутися.

Українська граматика 2019

> § 120. Дієприслівник
>
> 2. Дієприслівники минулого часу утворюємо від основи дієслова минулого часу чоловічого роду за допомогою суфікса -ши (після основи на
>    приголосний) і -вши (після основи на голосний): брав — бра́вши,
>    купува́в — купува́вши, купи́в — купи́вши, налеті́в — налеті́вши;
>    прині́с — прині́сши, спік — спі́кши, став — ста́вши.

На основі

> І так любо, допавши зміни,
>
> Налітати, мов княжа рать.

Тобто вчасно схопили, оновили останні військові технології, що схоже було наче нападають спеціальні війська князів.